# React draggable list component (with Hooks) keeps re-rendering, causing it to break. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to React (and React Hooks) so I apologize if the problem is obvious.  I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it's not working.

**What I want**

I have a simple list with draggable items.  I can rearrange the list simply by dragging and item and moving it somewhere else.

**What I get**

Choosing an item, and saving as the `targetItem` variable, allows me to move the item one space, either up or down, but then the component is re-rendered, causing `targetItem` to be `undefined`, breaking my component.

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ListItem = ({
        item,
        index,
        dragStart,
        dragEnter,
        drop
    }) => {
    return (
        <li
            onDragEnter={(event) => dragEnter(event, index)} 
            onDrop={(event) => drop(event)}
        >
            <div
                draggable="true"
                onDragStart={(event) => dragStart(event, index)}
            >
                <span>{item}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};


const List = () => {
    const [ getItems, setItems ] = useState([
        " Cake",
        " Donut",
        " Apple",
        " Pizza"
    ]);

    let targetItem;

    const dragStart = (event, index) => {
        targetItem = getItems[index];
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    };

    const dragEnter = (event, index) => {
        console.log("--", index, targetItem);
        const sourceItem = getItems[index];

        if (targetItem !== sourceItem) {
            const items = getItems.filter((item) => item !== targetItem);
            items.splice(index, 0, targetItem);

            setItems(items);
        }
    };

    const drop = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>My List</h3>
            <ul>
                {getItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <ListItem
                        key={Math.random()}
                        item={item}
                        index={index}
                        dragStart={dragStart}
                        dragEnter={dragEnter}
                        drop={drop}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default List;
```

Comment: Whenever you call `setItems()` it triggers a re-render of your `List` component, which in turn creates a new scope where `targetItem` is `undefined` again. Your `dragEnter()` calls `setItems()`, triggering such a re-render. The solution would be to initialize `targetItem` similarly to how `getItems` was initialized, using a `useState()` hook.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much @PatrickRoberts.  If you post this comment as an answer I will gladly mark it as the correct one.  Also, if you see something else in my code that looks strange, isn't optimized or goes against convention I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the unstable key of the

```
<ListItem
   key={Math.random()}
```

is the key here (no pun intended). By assigning random keys, your forcing React to re-render all `<ListItem>` with new DOM nodes when the `<List>` is rendered, because React cannot correlate them with the previous ones.

Try to give each item a stable, meaningful keys. Array index could be a solution, but it in most cases considered as an anti-pattern. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html and also [this blog post](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: That is indeed the most fundamental rule of React. **keep** the keys **identical** across rendering for DOM elements which should not re-render.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but If I change the code to `key={item}`, it still doesn't work and I get this in in the console: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: Actually, it works and I no longer receive the error after I fixed the real problem, which was solved in an above comment. While your answer is definitely helpful, it wasn't the solution to the problem.